# Where to put super() or this() in my classes

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee, build, compiler-errors

I have a Servlet class I made to handle functions I don't want to repeat on every Servlet I have.  I'm still working on it (i.e. it still only loads index.jsp and not other files).

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public MyServlet () {
        super();
    }

    public void loadView (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        System.out.println("MyServlet::LoadView() success");

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

My Servlet is as follows

```
@WebServlet(name = "EditServlet", urlPatterns = {"/content/edit"})
public class EditServlet extends Library.MyServlet {
    public EditServlet () {
        super();
    }

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("EditServlet loaded");
    }
}
```

I am however, unable to compile my code:

```
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [ContentManagement] : (class: contentmanagement/content/EditServlet, method: <init> signature: ()V) Constructor must call super() or this()
```

**update**

Ok, removing `void` on my constructors and calling `super();` got the `must call first` portion to go away, but it's still saying I have to call super despite that it's already being called.

**update**

I don't understand the responses below.... they keep saying to put `super()` within the constructor, when my examples already show that being done, AND it is the first line of code.  Any other advice would be appreciated.

Any thoughts?

**This is now a non-issue.  I do not know what resolved this issue, but with multiple changes and rebuilding my app from the ground up I am no longer experiencing this issue**

Comment: If you get an error stating that it must be first, did you try putting it first in the constructor?

Comment: A constructor doesn't have any return type. Remove the void before MyServlet and EditServlet. Does the code compile?

Comment: Are you using Netbeans? I recall a similar question about this Netbeans quirk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560988/method-must-call-super-error-in-netbeans In other words, your build is dirty. For example, you've manually renamed/moved class files in the project by a file explorer instead of by the IDE. Those constructors are by the way totally unnecessary. The servlet should work equally good without any of them (after you have cleaned your dirty classpath of course).

Comment: @BalusC - Yes I'm using Netbeans.  I've tried refactoring files and renaming the classes and stuff and it hasn't resolved the issue.  I also deleted the project and recreated it.

Comment: No, that won't solve it. It are `.class` files which exist in build folder which isn't associated with any `.java` source file in your IDE's project. You need to clean it at file system level. Best would be to delete the entire `/build` folder (or whatever it's called in Netbeans, I've never used it for more than 5 minutes, in Eclipse it's at least `/bin`) and let Netbeans rebuild the project.

Comment: I've now deleted the `/build` directory and I'm still getting the error when I `Clean and Build`

Comment: What if you create a brand new project with only one simple Hello World `@WebServlet` which does basically `response.getWriter().write("Hi")` in `doGet()`? All with all, this is definitely a Netbeans problem. Oh, please use `@nickname` to notify others about comment replies on posts which are not their own. I didn't get notified of your last comment.

Comment: @BalusC - Gotcha, I had no idea that notified you.... I recreated the project from scratch and copy/pasted all my code back in.  This still doesn't work.  I did what you suggested and it works.... hrmm... any thoughts?

Comment: I am going to start with this fresh project and add step by step until I figure out the exact problem

Comment: At least, remove those constructors altogether. They are totally unnecessary and won't solve anything. I have only my doubts about `extends Library.MyServlet` in your code. This is an odd naming convention. This suggests that `Library` is another class in which you have nested `MyServlet` as a static class. Is this true? Or is it just a bad package name?

Comment: @BalusC - Why do you say it's a bad package name?  Either I `extend MyServlet` and import the file, or to avoid an import, I can `extend LIbrary.MyServlet`

Comment: It is not conform [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). It is not all-lowercase. It does not represent a "domain". It look like a class name. Such a package is therefore confusing and misleading to normal Java programmers. Language-specific code conventions are very important to make your code quickly understandable and maintainable by the rest of the world.

Comment: Also, an call to super without arguments is unnecessary: this is implicit and can thus be left out. super()-calls are only necessary when they have at least one parameter in it.

Comment: @BalusC - So it should be `Library.myServlet` ?

Comment: Uh no. As said, **package** should be all lowercase. Click the "Java Naming Conventions" link.

Comment: @BalusC - In a standard MVC web app, how do you structure your packages?  Your profile shows how experienced you are with Java and I'd love to pick your brain a little bit.

Comment: Depends. In your case I'd start with `org.webnet.controller.MyServlet` or something.

Comment: @BalusC - Even though it loads with just `library.myServlet`, I should specify the whole thing so you know exactly where it's coming from...

Comment: I don't understand you. You mean, without importing it? Well, makes no sense to me. I'd rather give the servlet class a sensible name so that you don't need to put the package in front to figure what kind of servlet it is. But we go offtopic. Go fix your problems :)

Comment: @BalusC - So you're saying I should have `extends myServlet` and import the class, or I should just extend `org.webnet.controller.myServlet` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem was:

`method: <init> signature: ()V) Constructor must call super() or this()`

It seems like `VerifyError` symptom. Cleaning and rebuilding the project should resolve the problem, see also:

- [VerifyError means the bytecode is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3019394/1064325)
- [Perform a "clean and build"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6560988/1064325)

---

Furthermore, you can remove your constructors with a `super()` single-line. The JVM does it for you with a default (implicitly hidden) constructor. So, clear these unnecessary lines:

```
public MyServlet () {
    super();
}
```

and

```
public EditServlet () {
    super();
}
```

You would have to explicitly call `super()` if you needed to write additional business lines in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

And how does the constructor of `Library.MyServlet` look?. As a note, if the `super` keyword is to be used in a constructor, it *has* to be on the first line. Same thing for `this`.

Have you tried deleting the empty constructor? Apparently, you're not using it.

Comment: @Webnet It's not clear since in your code it reads `extends Library.MyServlet`, but the code you've shown is for `MyServlet`. If they're the same, then try writing `super()` in the first line of `EditServlet`, or delete the `EditServlet` constructor

Comment: `MyServlet` is part of the library package, I'm not sure I understand what isn't clear.  Even when I delete the constructor on `EditServlet` there's still an error on `MyServlet`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Library.MyServlet` has a constructor that takes no arguments, this should work:

```
public class EditServlet extends Library.MyServlet {
    public EditServlet () {
        super();
        // Rest of initialization code...
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just clean and build...
It's a build issue, your class is perfectly normal now. Sometimes when you correct the code the IDE just recompile parts of your code and not the entire code. A clean and build should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you use `this()` or `super()`, it must be the *first* line of the constructor.

However, if you need to do some work *before* calling `this()` or `super()`, you can use this pattern:

```
public MyClass () {
    this(someStaticMethod());
}
```

or

```
public MyClass () {
    super(someStaticMethod());
}
```

And craft other private constructors to suit.

The methods you call can't be instance methods, so it doesn't work for all cases, but it may help you.

Comment: It `is` the first line of my constructor, look at my code :-\