# java.lang.VerifyError when deploying the new version of my Java EE web application

Tags: spring, maven, equals, java-7, maven-glassfish-plugin

I modified some code in my current web project to add Spring transaction management. Everything works just fine when I deploy it in Eclipse or even when I call a "Maven clean" and a "Maven install" in my workspace. However when my continuous integration server (jenkins) tries to redeploy it on my distant server I get a  java.lang.VerifyError and it fails:

```
maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) @ myApp --- [INFO] asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile C:\Windows\TEMP\mgfp2047875868831547735.tmp --interactive=false --echo=true --terse=true deploy --name myApp --force=false --precompilejsp=false --verify=false --enabled=true --generatermistubs=false --availabilityenabled=false --keepreposdir=false --keepfailedstubs=false --logReportedErrors=true --upload=false --help=false C:\.jenkins\workspace\First_deploy\target\myApp-0.0.1.war
[ERROR] com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CommandException: remote failure: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'analysisDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource] while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'expressionHandler' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expressionHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'projectPermissionEvaluator' while setting bean property 'permissionEvaluator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectPermissionEvaluator': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public fr.services.interfaces.IProjectService fr.services.security.ProjectPermissionEvaluator.projectService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public fr.services.interfaces.IProjectRightsService fr.services.impl.ProjectService.projectRightService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectRightService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public fr.dao.IDAOFactory fr.services.impl.ProjectRightService.daoFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myAppDAOFactory': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agriculturalToolDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 43 in method fr.model.application.Projet.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z at offset 4
```

I use a jdk1.7 (I checked on my server and it's still the right JDK which is in the environment variables), maven and Glassfish. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>means</groupId>
    <artifactId>means</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mavenplugin-server</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>environment</name>
                    <value>server</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <glassfish.home>C:\MEANS\Glassfish\glassfish</glassfish.home>
                <glassfish.adminPort>4848</glassfish.adminPort>
                <glassfish.httpPort>8080</glassfish.httpPort>
                <glassfish.httpsPort>8443</glassfish.httpsPort>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mavenplugin-server-production</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>environment</name>
                    <value>server-production</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <glassfish.home>C:\MEANS\Glassfish\glassfish</glassfish.home>
                <glassfish.adminPort>4949</glassfish.adminPort>
                <glassfish.httpPort>8282</glassfish.httpPort>
                <glassfish.httpsPort>8553</glassfish.httpsPort>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mavenplugin-local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <glassfish.home>C:\MEANS\Glassfish\glassfish</glassfish.home>
                <glassfish.adminPort>4848</glassfish.adminPort>
                <glassfish.httpPort>8080</glassfish.httpPort>
                <glassfish.httpsPort>8443</glassfish.httpsPort>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <eclipselink.version>2.4.0</eclipselink.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>http:// repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
            <url>http:// repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>build2</outputDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>${basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <warSourceExcludes>${basedir}\WebContent\*</warSourceExcludes>
                    <resource>
                        <excludes>
                            <directory>${basedir}/WebContent</directory>
                            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}\src\fr</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF\classes\fr</targetPath>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}\build2\fr</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF\classes\fr</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>dispatcher-servlet.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>dispatcher-servlet.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>log4j.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/META-INF</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>persistence.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/WebContent/</directory>
                            <targetPath></targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration> 
                    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <user>admin</user>
                    <echo>true</echo>
                    <adminPassword>means2012!</adminPassword>
                    <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                    <domain>
                        <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                        <adminPort>${glassfish.adminPort}</adminPort>
                        <httpPort>${glassfish.httpPort}</httpPort>
                        <httpsPort>${glassfish.httpsPort}</httpsPort>
                    </domain>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
  </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.sdo</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.oracle</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried to add the maven-surefire-plugin as indicated in this post: [How do I get unit test to run in java 7: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638143/how-do-i-get-unit-test-to-run-in-java-7-java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stac) but without success... As I'm not a maven expert, it's extremely difficult to find out what is wrong in my configuration so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you keep the security info in the database or an LDAP?

Comment: I'd suggest you add the `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` as a configuration into the maven-glassfish-plugin and not the surefire. Surefire is for running JUnit tests and your build is failing at deployment into glassfish

Comment: I corrected the configuration as you suggested but without success, I still have the same error... Here is my configuration now: <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>

Comment: I said `maven-glassfish-plugin` **not** maven-war-plugin

Comment: Ok sorry I was too quick and didn't read properly... I changed it on the maven-glassfish-plugin as following: <plugin> <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>   <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<configuration>
<user>admin</user>
<echo>true</echo>
...
<components><component>
...
</component>
</components>
<domain>
...
</domain>
<argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
</configuration>
</plugin> It sill doesn't work. Is it the correct configuration line this time?

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122890/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame-at-branch-target-jdk-1-7

Comment: @Ralph: I saw this question before so I tried the workarounds... but it still doesn't work for me (am I doing something wrong with my plugin configuration?). Could a problem in my code explain this error? (I don't have any java compilation error) I don't really like the solution to change my JRE to 1.6, it has been a year I develop with a JDK1.7 without any trouble...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it might help somebody some day, I solved this problem and everything works again with my app now... 
The problem came from the glassfish installation so it had nothing to do with my code (even if this weird "VerrifyError" pointed out some code line). I found out that if I deployed it on another glassfish it worked so I re-installed my Glassfish server and my problem was solved! Too bad I spent more than a week on that... Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what I'm seeing in your stack trace, I believe the application is unable to connect to the database or an LDAP.  This causes the autowiring of one of the beans to fail which then cascades over into the other beans.

Ensure that the application can properly connect to any external resources required by the beans.

Comment: I keep the security info in the database... I didn't change anything in my database configuration and everything worked just fine before. I'll check again...

Comment: @Coralie when you said it worked fine before do you mean in eclipse or on the server?

Comment: on the server as well as in eclipse... I've updated the application on the server regularly for one year using this maven configuration without any trouble. It's the first time I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, AspectJ support Java 7 only from version 1.7.0 and upwards.

You may try to upgrade your AspectJ versions from 1.6.11 to 1.7.3 (which is the lastest available).

Comment: I did the upgrade but it doesn't solve the problem... I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question searching for that exception related to openCSV 2.3 and Java 7. In my case the exception was thrown when instantiating by reflection a class with references to opencsv classes. Maybe you have a similar problem. I resolved mine switching to [jcsv](https://code.google.com/p/jcsv/)

Comment: It wasn't the cause of my problem (see my solution) but thanks anyway for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by changing application class loader to "PARENT LAST".

Application-->Enterprise Application -->  --classloader mode =PARENT LAST