# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 73

Tags: java, maven, java-7, verifyerror

i use jdk 1.7, jekins, maven, when i build the project,the unit test fails, the error is :

> java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 73
>   Exception Details:   Location:
>       com/DataDictDao.save(Lcom/DataDict;)Ljava/lang/Long; @25: ldc   Reason:
>       Expected stackmap frame at this location.   Bytecode:
>       0000000: 033d 11ff ff3e 1212 1100 25b8 0018 2ab4
>       0000010: 0022 122d b900 3302 0012 1211 0027 b800
>       0000020: 182a b400 352b b900 3a02 0012 1211 0028
>       0000030: b800 182a b400 2212 3cb9 0033 0200 1212
>       0000040: 1100 2cb8 0018 a700 2d12 1211 0029 b800
>       0000050: 183a 0412 1211 002a b800 182a b400 2212
>       0000060: 3e19 04b9 0042 0300 1212 1100 2bb8 0018
>       0000070: 1904 bf12 1211 002d b800 182b b600 48b8
>       0000080: 004e b0                                   Exception Handler Table:
>       bci [25, 62] => handler: 73   Stackmap Table:
>       same_locals_1_stack_item_extended(@81,Object[#43])
>       same_frame(@123)
>
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493) at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901) at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:231)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1002)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:975)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211) at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

and i tried -noverify and -XX:-UseSplitVerifier in maven MAVEN_OPTS, neither worked, can anybody tells me why i get this error, how to solve it ?

Comment: Are you asking "why do I get this error?" (in which case we'd need to know more - are you using any Java agents, AspectJ, etc.) or are you asking "I know why I get this error, but why can't I suppress it/why can't I disable the verifier?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get unit test to run in java 7: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638143/how-do-i-get-unit-test-to-run-in-java-7-java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stac)

Comment: thank you, i have changed my question, and also i have added <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine> ,but it doesn't work

Comment: where com.DataDictDao class is defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958267/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame)

Comment: finally this problem was fixed, the cause is that a plugin is built using jdk 1.6

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. The solution was to add `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` to the surefire plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine> -XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

(Unrelated details of my plugin config omitted.)

I'm using JDK 1.7 and maven 3.2.3.

For JDK 1.8, use:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine> -noverify </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Where do I add this plugin configuration? Thanks.

Comment: @Sarin In your maven pom.xml file under <build>. You can also refer to https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're using java 1.8, then do the followings
1. Windows -> Preferences -> Installed JRE.
2. Select jdk/jre and select edit.
3. In default VM arguments, give "-noverify " .