# java exception verifyError in NetBeans

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, verifyerror

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019394/java-lang-verifyerror-on-method-that-worked-a-minute-ago) is similar, but didn't work.
I copied and pasted my project folder (because all I need is a different background image for a different client), then opened the copied project with NetBeans and run it. This error arises on startup:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return in method com.einge.scadaremotecontrol.ProgramacionAuto.<init>(Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;I)V at offset 0
```

The original project works just fine (I close one to run the other, so as not to get confused or have two identical programs running in the VM). What could be the problem? 
NetBeans is 7.1.2 JDK is 7u5
Thanks in advance

Edit: I have just tried it in an other computer and it works fine (NB 7.1, JDK 7u3 it think) Still have no idea what happened back there. If any solutions come up they will be welcomed.

Comment: I could simply create a new project and copy all the classes, then refactor them.. but I'd like to save the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the project first. Most probably it will take care of it.

If not, rebuild it, exit netbeans. Then reopen after few seconds. This is what I do in JavaFX unexpected build errors.

Comment: I couldn't make that work, although I moved the project to another computer and it worked great! Wierd.. I'm fine with this although I'd like to know why this happened and how to fix it in the future
Probably it recomipled itself when I moved it.
Thank you for your answer though !!